# Disable listview highlight for 1 or more columns when fullrowselect is true

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have a listview with 5 columns. It is ownerdraw.details view. the option for fullrowselect is true but how to avoid lets say the last column to be highlighted when row is selected? or to be more precisely, for this particular listview I need only the first 2 columns do be enabled for a click/select and only these first 2 columns would get the default highlight.

Comment: Add a minimal code example. What did you try so far?

Comment: Hello Jeroen, so far I've tried the listview.HitTest on MouseUp event, passing the index to the listview for selection, but I set the fullrowselect to false, now I am trying to highlight the second column because only the first one is highlight, but I have picture on it so it almost can't notice the row that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using the following solution:
Assuming you have your listview OwnerDraw = True, DrawItem/DrawSubItem = e.DrawDefault = true; FullRowSelect = False; HideSelection = False; you can place the below code in the desired ListView MouseUp Event, where "myListViewName" replacing for your listiview name:

```
        foreach (ListViewItem lstview in myListViewName.Items)//cleaning and resetting the original/default colors for all items as not selected.
        {
            lstview.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

            lstview.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.White; //settings for column 2 only
            lstview.SubItems[1].ForeColor = Color.Black; //settings for column 2 only
        }

        var info = myListViewName.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); //getting the row index for the item selected.
        var row = info.Item.Index;
        myListViewName.Items[row].Selected = true; //passing the index to the listview to be selected
        myListViewName.Items[row].SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue; //changing color of single row/column selected
        myListViewName.Items[row].SubItems[1].ForeColor = Color.White; //changing color of single row/column selected
```

Hope the solution can help out there, in my case, my listview have different colors for the extra columns and i did not want to loose the color when selecting the full row with the highlight default color. it can manage as many columns as you want.